# How to run an hourly cron job after another hourly cron job?

Tags: cron

I have an hourly job `A` that is configured and the script is placed under /etc/cron.hourly.

Now I have another job say `B` that also needs to be run hourly. However, one requirement is that the job `B` should run after job `A` since job `B` will consume some output by job `A`.

In this case how should I configure to run job `B`? Will placing it under /etc/cron.hourly work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single crontab entry that runs both jobs.

For example, you can add this script to your `/etc/cron.hourly` directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
A
B
```

Note that unless this is a system-level task, it's probably better to put it in a user crontab entry rather than messing with files under `/etc`:

```
0 * 0 0 0     A ; B
```